# Why won't my server open files?

Tags: ruby

I've been working on this code and for some reason the server can't open the index file, and I can't understand why. I've checked other people's code and there doesn't look like there is a difference.

Here is my code:

```
require 'socket'

class Server

  def initialize (base, request, server_name, session, charset)
    @base = base
    @request = request
    @charset = charset
    @server_name = server_name
    @session = session
    serve()
  end
  def serve ()
    access_log()
    getAddress()
    @contentType = getContentType()
    @session.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: #{@server_name}\r\nContent-Type: #{@contentType}; charset=@{charset}\r\n\r\n"
    getFile()
    @base = nil
    @request = nil
    @server_name = nil
    @contentType
    @session.close
    puts "Session Ended\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    @session = nil
  end
  def access_log ()
    log = File.open(@base + "data/access_log.txt", "w")
    log.puts "#{Time.now.localtime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{@session.peeraddr[2]}:#{@session.peeraddr[1]} #{@request}" unless log == nil
    log.close
    log = nil
  end
  def getAddress ()
    @src = @request
    @src.gsub!(/GET /, '').gsub!(/ HTTP.*/, '')
    @src.strip
    @src = @base + "root" + @src
    @src.gsub!('/', '\\')
  end
  def getContentType ()
    ext = nil
    ext = File.extname(@src)
    return "text/html"    if ext == ".html" or ext == ".htm"
    return "text/plain"   if ext == ".txt"
    return "text/css"     if ext == ".css"
    return "image/jpeg"   if ext == ".jpeg" or ext == ".jpg"
    return "image/gif"    if ext == ".gif"
    return "image/bmp"    if ext == ".bmp"
    return "text/plain"   if ext == ".rb"
    return "text/xml"     if ext == ".xml"
    return "text/xml"     if ext == ".xsl"
    #return "image/x-icon" if ext == ".ico" or ext == ".icon"
    return "text/html"
  end
  def getFile ()
      begin
    if !File.exist?(@src)
      puts "File: #{@src} could not be found"
      if @contentType.include?("image")
        file = File.open(@base + "root/server_files/broken_image.png", "r").each do |code|
          @session.puts code
        end
      else
        file = File.open(@base + "root/server_files/error404.html", "r").each do |code|
          @session.puts code
        end
      end
    else
      puts "File #{@src} was opened"
      file = File.open(@src, "r").each do |code|
        @session.puts code
      end
    end
      ensure
    file.close unless file == nil
      end
  end
end

base = "C:\\Base\\"
server_name = "Some Server"
host = "localhost"
port = 80
charset = "UFT-8"

server = TCPServer.new(host, port)
puts "~ Server hosted on #{host}:#{port} ~\n====================================\n"

loop {
  Thread.new(server.accept) do |session|
    request = session.gets
    puts "#{session.peeraddr[2]}:#{session.peeraddr[1]} #{request}"
    Server.new(base, request, server_name, session, charset)
  end
}

p = gets.chomp
server.close
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Does the code run as a different user or have permission to read the files?

Comment: You have to give us a bit more than "This won't work. Here's my code. Why it broken?"

Comment: I'd suggest outputting the full name of the index file (before opening it) to the console then seeing if that file exists or not...

Comment: I also suggest trimming this down to the bare minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.  You might find the problem in the process, but at the very least you'll make is a lot easier for people to wrap their heads around the problem.

Comment: With a heap of `return` statements, I'd suggest you need a `case` there to handle the various options.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with the code. I don't know if these directly cause the problem, but there's enough code smell that the following *untested* changes might help.

Don't use CamelCase method names in Ruby. We use snake_case.

```
require 'socket'

class Server

  def initialize(base, request, server_name, session, charset)

    @base = base
    @request = request
    @charset = charset
    @server_name = server_name
    @session = session

    serve()

  end

  def serve

    access_log
    get_address()
    @content_type = get_content_type()
    @session.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: #{@server_name}\r\nContent-Type: #{@content_type}; charset=@{charset}\r\n\r\n"
    get_file()
    @content_type
    @session.close
    puts "Session Ended\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    @base = @request = @server_name = @session = nil

  end
```

I don't know why you have `@content_type` on its own line prior to `@session.close`. It's not a method call, nor does it look like it's going to return anything to the server or the outgoing data-stream.

```
  def access_log

    File.open(File.join(@base, "data/access_log.txt"), "w") do |log|
      log.puts "#{Time.now.localtime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{@session.peeraddr[2]}:#{@session.peeraddr[1]} #{@request}"
    end

  end
```

Ruby's `File.open` takes a block. When the block exits the file will be closed automatically. `File.join` is the proper way to build a path. Ruby is aware of the proper path delimiters and will use them automatically, helping to make your code more portable.

```
  def get_address

    src = @request.gsub(/GET /, '').gsub(/ HTTP.*/, '').strip
    @src = (@base + "root" + src).gsub('/', '\\')

  end
```

You're doing a lot of `gsub!` for no reason. Chain them, combine the string, do a final `gsub` and move on.

```
  def get_content_type()

    ext = File.extname(@src)

    content_type = case ext
                   when /\.html?/
                     "text/html" 
                   when ".txt" 
                     "text/plain"
                   when ".css" 
                     "text/css"  
                   when /\.jpe?g/
                     "image/jpeg"
                   when ".gif" 
                     "image/gif" 
                   when ".bmp" 
                     "image/bmp" 
                   when ".rb"  
                     "text/plain"
                   when /\.x[ms]l/
                     "text/xml"  
                   else
                     "text/html"
                   end

    content_type

  end
```

It's confusing to have multiple `returns` in a sub-routine or method, so this cleans it up. The final `content_type` will be returned as the result of the method call. Using `case/when` lets you use multiple tests for each `when`, reducing line-noise.

```
  def get_file()
    begin

      if !File.exist?(@src)

        puts "File: #{@src} could not be found"
        if @content_type["image"]
          File.open(File.join(@base, "root", "server_files", "broken_image.png"), "rb") do |image|
            @session.puts image.read
          end
        else
          File.foreach(File.join(@base, "root", "server_files", "error404.html")) do |li|
            @session.puts li
          end
        end

      else

        puts "File #{@src} was opened"
        File.foreach(@src) do |li|
          @session.puts li
        end

      end

    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
    end
  end
```

When you want to read a binary file, such as "broken_image.png", ALWAYS open it in binary mode: `"rb"`. Otherwise, Ruby will assume it's OK to translate line-endings to the native format for the OS, which would corrupt the data. Also, again, use the block-forms of the File methods so they automatically close. And, use `File.join` for portability. When you're reading a text file, use `File.foreach` to read it line-by-line, unless you KNOW it will fit into the available memory; "Slurping" your files is bad form because it isn't scalable.

```
end

base = "C:/Base/"
server_name = "Some Server"
host = "localhost"
port = 80
charset = "UFT-8"

server = TCPServer.new(host, port)
puts "~ Server hosted on #{host}:#{port} ~\n====================================\n"

loop {
  Thread.new(server.accept) do |session|
    request = session.gets
    puts "#{session.peeraddr[2]}:#{session.peeraddr[1]} #{request}"
    Server.new(base, request, server_name, session, charset)
  end
}

p = gets.chomp
server.close
```

The code changes are available at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6515451